# get collection of documents with firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was following this example:

```
var docRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");

docRef.get().then(function(doc) {
    if (doc.exists) {
        console.log("Document data:", doc.data());
        // this is not working
        const people = doc.collection("people");
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

I want to return an array of people within the city of SF.

According to https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data

> when you fetch data at a location in your database, you also retrieve all of its child nodes.

but I can´t find the right to return the collection within a doc (without making a new query)

Comment: you are mixing two things the example is from firestore and the link is of RTDB. both are different kinds of databases

Comment: ohh.. I guess I have the wrong documentation. thank you! what would be the way to get the collection with firestore? do you happen to know?

Comment: do you have an example of what your data structure looks like?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data read the docs they contain everythin you need to know

Comment: I guess is not possible to do. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#list_subcollections_of_a_document

Comment: you should be able to use db.collection('cities').doc('SF').collection('people')

Comment: You can only query one collection at a time.  You will have to perform two queries if you are trying to "join" two collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Firestore when you retrieve the data, you retrieve all the fields inside a document. If you want to retrieve data from another document or from subcollection then you need to do a different query.